# Eclipse doesn't support C++ Project types

Tags: c++, eclipse

I want to start a C++ Project using eclipse,

but I found that some of the project types are not available in it after I had checked the
CheckBox - **"Show project types and toolchains only if they are supported on the platform"**

Only **"Makefile project > Hello World C++ Project"** is available in eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does support you have to download Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers which can be found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/).